# Does a good pronunciation improve one's ability to learn a language?

Tags: phonetics, pronunciation

My father is a native Spanish speaker. He struggles with English pronunciation, and even though he has studied many English courses, he seems to be stuck. Once I talked with a phonetics teacher, with whom I don't have any contact now, and he told me that if an English learner learns to pronounce well in the early stages (or in any stage) of their learning process, then they would learn more rapidly.

I remember that he told me, that if a person pronounces well a certain word, when someone else says the word, then the brain would recognize and understand the word much quicker than if the person would pronounce it wrongly.

I haven't had luck in finding papers that support this idea. Does anyone have any references to research on this topic?

Thanks a lot for your help.

PS I write here and not in http://ell.stackexchange.com because this site looks more scientific.

Comment: I read your last paragraph, but still I think this question may better fit at [Language Learning.SE](http://languagelearning.stackexchange.com/). The simple reason is that you're rather asking about methodology of learning and didactics, not about the intrinsic properties of languages.

Comment: @bytebuster Thanks I'll ask there. Shall I delete the question here?

Comment: @VladimirVargas I disagree with bytebuster. I think your question is very much about linguistics. I have no references on this, but I would expect that learners who can learn to differentiate between, for example, voiced and unvoiced phonemes when no such contrast is found in their L1, in terms of their production, will also have more success in terms of being able to recognise these phonemes when listening (I am thinking, for example, of English /s/ and /z/ for Spainish speakers). I would expect that to have a knock on effect in terms of their language acquisition. But this is just a theory.

Comment: @VladimirVargas I would be shocked if there wasn't some proper linguistic research on this.

Comment: @Araucaria I have just found something that is remotely related with my question: https://iris.ucl.ac.uk/iris/publication/1181018/1

However this does not have anything to do with the learning process